# Managing text within table cells

Tags: tables, spacing, graphics, line

When creating a table in latex and inserting a text inside a specific cell, if the text is long, this is the result:

[image]

Even if there is enough space in the cell to contain the whole sentence.
Moreover, I would like to like to start writing from the upper-right corner of the cell and not the bottom-right.

The code that gives me this error is here reported:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ |c| c| }
    \hline
        {\includegraphics[scale=0.35,keepaspectratio]{png_Images/read_actor.png}}
        & 
        \begin{tabular}[]{@{}l@{}}
        This actor is in charge of performing the action of reading
        the image from the memory. 
        \end{tabular}
        \\ 
        \hline
        {\includegraphics[scale=0.3,keepaspectratio]{png_Images/tiling.png}} 
        & cap2  \\
        \hline
        {\includegraphics[scale=0.35,keepaspectratio]{png_Images/filter.png}} 
        & cap3  \\
        \hline
        {\includegraphics[scale=0.35,keepaspectratio]{png_Images/merge.png}}
        & cap4  \\
        \hline
        {\includegraphics[scale=0.35,keepaspectratio]{png_Images/save.png}} 
        & cap5  \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you post a compilable code?

Comment: replace l in \begin{tabular}[]{@{}l@{}} by p{10cm} (or any other width) to obtain  automatical wrapping, see e.g. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabular_environment

Comment: Use a p type colum or have a look at the tabularx package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load `adjustbox` and use `valign=c` with `\includegraphics`, and `m{some length}`  for the second column. Last, I added some vertical padding around cells in the 1st column with the `cellspace` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}%
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} 

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ |Sc| m{0.4\linewidth}| }
    \hline
        {\includegraphics[scale=0.35,keepaspectratio, valign = c]{png_Images/read_actor.png}}
        &
        This actor is in charge of performing the action of reading
        the image from the memory.
        \\
        \hline
        {\includegraphics[scale=0.3,keepaspectratio, valign=c]{png_Images/tiling.png}}
        & cap2 \\
        \hline
        {\includegraphics[scale=0.35,keepaspectratio, valign=c]{png_Images/filter.png}}
        & cap3 \\
        \hline
        {\includegraphics[scale=0.35,keepaspectratio, valign=c]{png_Images/merge.png}}
        & cap4 \\
        \hline
        {\includegraphics[scale=0.35,keepaspectratio, valign=c]{png_Images/save.png}}
        & cap5 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: LaTeX Error: Option clash for package graphicx.

Comment: the solution give error on Overleaf

Comment: Remove the `demo` option – it was there jut because I don't have your graphic files. What error do you have, other than the option clash?

Comment: +1 no error now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variant that uses `tabularx` `X` type column for the second column as well as a different vertical alignment (`valign=t`). Similar to [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/507112/134144), I have also used the `cellspace` package to add a symmetric white border around the images (=white space above and below equals `\tabcolsep`)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\tabcolsep}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}%
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |Sc| X | }
    \hline
        {\includegraphics[scale=0.35,keepaspectratio, valign = t]{png_Images/read_actor.png}}
        &
        This actor is in charge of performing the action of reading
        the image from the memory.
        \\
        \hline
        {\includegraphics[scale=0.3,keepaspectratio, valign=t]{png_Images/tiling.png}}
        & cap2 \\
        \hline
        {\includegraphics[scale=0.35,keepaspectratio, valign=t]{png_Images/filter.png}}
        & cap3 \\
        \hline
        {\includegraphics[scale=0.35,keepaspectratio, valign=t]{png_Images/merge.png}}
        & cap4 \\
        \hline
        {\includegraphics[scale=0.35,keepaspectratio, valign=t]{png_Images/save.png}}
        & cap5 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (S): `c' used.

Comment: @Leos313: with the exact same example code from my answer or in your actual document?

Comment: ok, deleting the S avoid the problem and the code is correctly compiled

Comment: In your actual document, make sure, you load the cellspace` package.

Comment: Your line --> `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |Sc| X | }`

New line ---> `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |c| X | } `

Comment: you are right. However the result is the same. Isn't it?

Comment: @Leos313: If you delete the `S` from the code, the spacing of the images will be different. There will be no white space above and below the images. If you on the other hand add `\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\tabcolsep}` to your preamble and keep the `S`, there is a small white space all around the image (as you can see in the screenshot in my answer). So, the output will in fact not be the same.